# Как прервать запускаемую неинтерактивно программу?

Tags: linux, bash

Есть debian с некой утилитой, которая запускается "с руки" из консоли и умеет вычленять из tcp/ip-стека инфу по некой маске и далее через конвейер (pipeline) отдавать это в tcpdump который преобразует это в human readable format и отдаёт через конвейер прочим утилитам для работы с текстом (grep|awk|sed|strings|etc) ... в конце - результат перенаправляется в консоль.

Мне нужно всё это делать с помощью cron, но проблема в том, что пока этой утилите не пошлёшь KeyboardInterrupt она не освободит консоль и процесс не умрёт.

Собсно вопрос: Как-то можно сказать крону, либо bash'у , чтоб он через некоторое время прибивал бы этот процесс не костыляя ещё одного костыля?

Пример как "это" запускается:

```
$ stack_tmux -host 8.8.8.8 -port 53 | tcpdump -nl -s 0 -A -r - | strings | grep -v com | grep hello_world | cut -f 6 -d" " > /test.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться, например, программой `timeout` из [*gnu/coreutils*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Coreutils):

```
$ timeout 1.5 команда с аргументами
```

если `команда с аргументами` не завершится сама в течение полутора секунд, то ей будет послан сигнал `TERM`. можно указать и другой с помощью опции `-s сигнал`, например, требующийся вам `-s HUP`:

```
$ timeout -s HUP 100 stack_tmux -host 8.8.8.8 -port 53 | tcpdump ...
```

---

подробнее: [`$ man timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation)