# Зависшие php скрипты в cron

Tags: php, cron, timeout

Есть сприпты, что по крону бегают на почту и загружают файлы, если те попадают под условия

Стартую так - точка входа:

```
*/1 0-3,7-23 * * *    /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/script/cron.php >/dev/null
```

Зависло 224 подобных вызовов:

```
pgrep -f /path/to/script/cron.php|wc -l
```

Там и от марта есть процессы, самый ранний:

```
Wed Mar 27 01:03:01 2019 28136 /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/script/cron.php
```

В начале скрипта делается `set_time_limit(180);` и больше ни где не переназначается, ни в инклудах ни в созданных классах, что используется
Мог проглядеть, но мало вероятно

Из-за чего еще может зависнуть скрипт?
Как бороться с недугом?

*...любые доводы, мысли, предположения...*

Comment: [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620383/178576)

Comment: лучше бы попробовать отладить скрипт путём записи отладочной информации в журнал